# Tkinter Code runs but not window does not show

Tags: python, tkinter

I noticed if I eliminate/comment the ###########  Create Dropdown list for Code corresponding name ########### section below, the window appears. Also, if I use the same code in a different file, the DropDown list appears as normal.... super weird!! 
Not sure what is going on here.
Can you help?
Code below:

```
from tkinter import *       

###########  Create main window, call it root  ###########
root = Tk()

#Defining classes and methods
class Code:

    def __init__(self, code, name, skill, description):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill
        self.description = description

        codesList.append(self)
        namesList.append(name)

#Defining variables
codesList = []
namesList = []

selectedname = StringVar()
selectedname.set('Please select the correct the correct knowledge category necessary to resolve the ticket.')

A11 = Code(11, 'Fundamentals', 'A', '')

B11 = Code(11,'Geology', 'B', '')
B12 = Code(12,'Reservoir Engineering', 'B', '')

###########  Create list of Dictionaries  ###########     
TypeD = {}
SiteD = {}
P4dcD = {}
SkillD = {}


###########  Create Incident Types  Dictionary###########
TypeD = dict(Normal='NORMAL', \
             Parent='PARENT', \
             Child='CHILD')
TypeNameL = list()
for i in TypeD.keys():
    TypeNameL.append(i)                                        


###########  Create Skill Levels  ###########
SkillD = dict(Awareness = 'A', \
              Foundation = 'B', \
              Skill = 'C', \
              Advance = 'D')
SkillNameL = list()
for i in SkillD.keys():
    SkillNameL.append(i)

###########  Create main menu  ########### 
mainmenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mainmenu)
submenu = Menu(mainmenu)

mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label = "New Project", command=doNothing)         
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command= exitmeth)

editmenu = Menu(mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Redo", command = doNothing)

###########  Toolbar  ###########
toolbar = Frame(root, bg="blue")                                                
insertButt = Button(toolbar, text = "Insert image", command = InsertImgcmd)      
insertButt.pack(side=LEFT, padx = 2, pady=2)                                    
printButt = Button(toolbar, text="Print", command = printP4dcD)
printButt.pack(side=LEFT, padx = 2, pady=2)

toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)                                              

###########  Create Dropdown list for Code corresponding name ###########
LabelCodeDDL = Label(root, text="Petrel Code").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
CodeDDL = OptionMenu(root, selectedname, *namesList)
CodeDDL.pack()
CodeDDL.configure(font=("Calibri", 11))
CodeDDL.grid(row=3, column=0)


##########  Statusbar  ##########
statusbar = Label(root, text='', bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
statusbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)                                        

root.title("Ticket Summary Tool")
root.geometry("300x200")
root.mainloop()
```

I should get some errors or the window should display. I can't figure out what is happening...

Comment: Is there some other code we need to see here as well? Where is `exitmeth` or `doNothing` defined for example?

Comment: You're right, there are a couple of methods defined but they don't do much yet, I am just trying to get the GUI set up and then I will worry about the commands: def doNothing():
    print("Okay I won't")
def exitmeth():
    exit()

Answer (score 1):

You are  using both `pack` and `grid` with widgets that are directly in `root` (for example, `LabelCodeDDL = Label(root, text="Petrel Code").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)` and `toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)`). You cannot mix them like that. All widgets that have the same parent or master must use one or the other.

Comment: It worked thanks!! changed it to:                                      
          ###########  Create Dropdown list for Code corresponding name ###########
LabelCodeDDL = Label(root, text="Petrel Code").pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)                                                                              CodeDDL = OptionMenu(root, selectedname, *namesList)
CodeDDL.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=W)
CodeDDL.configure(font=("Calibri", 11))